# Finding a Projector real world position (using OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, position, projector

I'm currently trying to discover the 3D position of a projector within a real world coordinate system. The origin of such a system is, for example, the corner of a wall. I've used Open Frameworks addon called [ofxCvCameraProjectorCalibration](https://github.com/kikko/ofxCvCameraProjectorCalibration)
 that is based on OpenCV functions, namely [calibrateCamera](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera) and [stereoCalibrate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#double%20stereoCalibrate%28InputArrayOfArrays%20objectPoints,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints1,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints2,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix1,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs1,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix2,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs2,%20Size%20imageSize,%20OutputArray%20R,%20OutputArray%20T,%20OutputArray%20E,%20OutputArray%20F,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20flags%29) methods. The application output is the following:

- camera intrisic matrix (distortion coeficients included);
- projector intrisic matrix (distortion coeficients included);
- camera->projector extrinsic matrix;

My initial idea was, while calibration the camera, place the chessboard pattern at the corner of the wall and extract the extrinsic parameters ( [RT] matrix ) for that particular calibration. 
After calibrating both camera and projector do I have all the necessary data to discover the position of the projector in real world coordinates? If so, what's the matrix manipulation required to get it?